# JUnit test for Anagram making program?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have to write junit tests for this part of code: but I have to tests everything, means not only `assertEquals(expected, actual)`, but also all exceptions which could be, all functionality.

```
public String reverseWords(String input) {
    String oneOrMoreSpaces = "\\s+";
    String[] words = input.split(oneOrMoreSpaces);
    String completeAnagram = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        char[] symbol = words[i].toCharArray();
        char newSymbolSequence;
        int j = symbol.length - 1, k = 0;

        while (k < j) {
            if (!Character.isAlphabetic(symbol[k]))
                k++;
            else if (!Character.isAlphabetic(symbol[j]))
                j--;
            else {
                newSymbolSequence = symbol[k];
                symbol[k] = symbol[j];
                symbol[j] = newSymbolSequence;
                k++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        completeAnagram = new String(symbol);
    }
    return completeAnagram;
}
```

This is what I've already made

```
private Anagram anagram = new Anagram();

@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void checkExpected_NullPointerException(){
    anagram.reverseWords(null);
}
@Test
public void reverseWords_shouldMakeAnagram_ofInputText(){
    String actual = anagram.reverseWords("qwe123rty");
    String expected = "ytr123ewq";
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
@Test
public void throwingTest(){
    String actual = anagram.reverseWords("qwe123rty");
    String expected = "qwe123rty";
    assertNotSame(expected, actual);
}
```

Can anyone help me with good `@Test` methods which really should be there. I have no idea what I can `@Test` else.

Answer (score 2):

Test some limit values:

```
String actual = anagram.reverseWords("");
String actual = anagram.reverseWords(" ");
String actual = anagram.reverseWords("q");
```

You're doing some logic with words so test this too:

```
String actual = anagram.reverseWords("more than a feeling");
String actual = anagram.reverseWords("azerty querty");
String actual = anagram.reverseWords("azerty ");
String actual = anagram.reverseWords(" azerty ");
```

spoiler: I think you will discover some bugs as `completeAnagram` is each time overwritten and only contains the last word.